# What happens on the memory when Windows Phone application sent to background?

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-management, windows-phone-8

How memory is managed if lot's of application is opened.

For example if user keeps opening apps and hits to windows button to turn back to home screen, how windows phone manages the memory?

Is there any limitation on this?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when an app gets dismissed it will remain in memory but will no longer get any CPU time and therefore saves power. However it can also be removed from memory e.g. tombstoned. Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on the states within the windows phone. The process of how to work with this state and getting back is described in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

HTH